# Why does Perl warn me about using pseudo-hashes?

Tags: perl, warnings

Perl is warning me about using pseudo hashs in my program:

> Pseudo-hashes are deprecated

How do I convert the following code so that is does not use pseudo hashs

```
    foreach my $hash (@arrayOfHash) {
            print keys %{$hash};
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem isn't in that code.  The problem is that `@arrayOfHash` actually contains arrayrefs, not hashrefs.

If for some reason you can't fix `@arrayOfHash`, you can work around it by doing:

```
foreach my $hash (@arrayOfHash) {
     my %hash = @$hash;
     print keys %hash;
}
```

Comment: "work around it" is a little generous given neither we nor the questioner seems to know what exactly is in @arrayOfHash. First figure that out, then do something about it.  Your code will only be helpful in one limited case of error.

Answer (score 5):

You should always post the full example code.....

Not sure what you're doing, but you're probably mixing arrays and array refs and/or hashes and hashrefs.  I usually only use references, as I like the syntax better and I like to be consistent:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my($arrayrefOfHashrefs) = [
                           {foo => 'bar',
                            bar => 'baz'},
                           {Hello => 'world'},
                          ];

foreach my $href (@$arrayrefOfHashrefs) {
    print join("\n", keys %$href);
    print "\n\n";
}
```

will print:

```
C:\Temp>perl foo.pl
bar
foo

Hello
```